# How can I specify how to choose between duplicate rows in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame (below) consisting of a first column (`ID`) that I want to make into the rownames. However, there are duplicates in this first column. However, rather than just using `!duplicated` to remove the duplicates, I want to use the rows that do **not** have an NA for a specificied column. For example the column named `UHU` in the example data below (or anyone that I would use as argument). What is the most efficient way of doing this without looping through each duplication and checking the original against its duplicate for an `NA`. I'd also like to be able to specify columns to check for NAs in an order of preference, i.e. first select duplicate with no NA for the `UHU` column, and if equal check duplicate in another column, etc.

```
structure(list(ID = c("A1_0SM", "A1_0SP", "A2_04U", 
"A2_04U", "A2_04U", "A2_04U", "A2_0CM", 
"A2_0CM", "A2_0CM", "A2_0CM", "A2_0CM", 
"A2_0CM", "A2_0D0", "A2_0D0", "A2_0D2", 
"A2_0D2", "A2_0D2", "A2_0SX", "A2_0SX", 
"A2_0SX", "A2_0SX", "A2_0SX", "A2_0T0", 
"A2_0T0", "A2_0T0", "A2_0T2", "A2_0YE", 
"A2_0YE", "A2_0YE", "A2_1G6", "A2_1G6", 
"A2_1G6", "A7_0DA", "A7_0DA", "A7_0DA", 
"A7_26G", "A7_26G", "A8_07C", "A8_07O", 
"A8_08R", "A8_09X", "AC_2QH", "AN_04D", 
"AN_0AL", "AN_0AR", "AN_0AT", "AN_0G0", 
"AN_0XU", "AO_03U", "AO_03U", "AO_03U", 
"AO_03U", "AO_03U", "AO_03U", "AO_0J4", 
"AO_0J4", "AO_0J4", "AO_0J6", "AO_0J6", 
"AO_0J6", "AO_0JL", "AO_0JL", "AO_0JL", 
"AO_0JL", "AO_124", "AO_124", "AO_124", 
"AO_128", "AO_128", "AO_128", "AO_128", 
"AO_129", "AO_129", "AO_129", "AO_12F", 
"AO_12F", "AO_12F", "AO_1MR", "AQ_04J", 
"AQ_04J", "AQ_04J", "AQ_04J", "AQ_04J", 
"AQ_04J", "AR_0TS", "AR_0TU", "AR_0U1", 
"AR_0U4", "AR_1AR", "AR_1AR", "AR_1AY", 
"AR_256", "AR_2LR", "BH_0B3", "BH_0B3", 
"BH_0B3", "BH_0B9", "BH_0B9", "BH_0BG", 
"BH_0BL"), UHU = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE), days_to_selection_end = c(NA, "172", "196", "119", 
"119", "670", "147", "147", "601", "615", "433", "NA", 
"125", "125", "123", "123", "179", "1359", "132", "1359", "132", 
"NA", "234", "234", "234", "212", "[Completed]", 
"[Completed]", "[Completed]", "172", "119", "119", "198", "107", 
"107", "151", "151", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "215", "215", "215", "215", "215", "215", "175", "203", "175", 
"172", "116", "116", "178", "493", "122", "122", "125", "125", 
"237", "124", "124", "124", "124", "161", "161", "161", "189", 
"189", "189", NA, "104", "104", "159", "104", "104", "159", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "213", "115", "115", "111", "111", 
NA, NA), days_to_selection_start = c(NA, "107", "133", "78", 
"78", "480", "98", "98", "391", "391", "391", "234", "62", "62", 
"74", "74", "137", "1289", "62", "1289", "62", "1429", "61", 
"61", "61", "92", "[Completed]", "[Completed]", "[Completed]", 
"132", "69", "69", "122", "65", "65", "89", "89", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "70", "70", "70", "70", "70", 
"70", "131", "189", "131", "130", "74", "74", "136", "136", "80", 
"80", "60", "60", "146", "82", "82", "82", "82", "67", "67", 
"67", "63", "63", "63", NA, "61", "61", "117", "61", "61", "117", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "136", "52", "52", "48", 
"48", NA, NA), selection_name = c(NA, "NA", "T0101tere", 
"nw8m100", "991xan", "kkw", "991xan", "nw8m100", "i11io18el", 
"Cape1000", "kkw", "99f101fen", "991xan", "i11io18el", 
"991xan", "nw8m100", "T0101l", "82eplan18", "nw8m100", 
"Gem1000", "991xan", "Xeloda", "T0101tere", "991xan", "nw8m100", 
"Xeloda", "T0101tere", "nw8m100", "991xan", "i11io18el", "nw8m100", 
"991xan", "T0101l", "nw8m100", "991xan", "991xan", "T0101tere", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "iu18101", "iu18101", 
"111o1018", "98aj", "98aj", "111o1018", 
"fox", "114iio18el", "teo882s", "114Iio18EL", 
"teO882s", "98aj", "114Iio18EL", "Uwm", 
"teO882s", "98aj", "teo882s", "98aj", 
"114iio18el", "98aj", "teo882s", "teo882s", 
"98aj", "98aj", "114iio18el", "teo882s", 
"114iio18el", "98aj", "teo882s", NA, "991xan", 
"991xan", "T0101l", "nw8m100", "nw8m100", "T0101l", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "114iio18el", "teo882s", 
"98aj", "teo882s", "98aj", NA, NA
)), .Names = c("ID", "UHU", "days_to_selection_end", 
"days_to_selection_start", "selection_name"), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You have both `NA` and `"NA"` in your dataframe. This is probably an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
DF[with(DF, ave(ID, ID, FUN=length)==1 | !is.na(UHU)),]
```

If there are still duplicates, you save the above result back in `DF` and run the call again, replacing `UHU` with your next column for checking `NA`s.